# Replacing key value pair with spaces using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a properties file and a json file. The property file holds the key value pairs which needs to be replaced in the json.

When the value has no spaces it works as expected, but when the value has spaces, the value is not replaced.

**Script that replaces the values**

```
#!bin/bash
echo hello

while read line;
do
#echo $line
key=$(echo "$line" |cut -d':' -f1)
#echo $part1
value=$(echo "$line" |cut -d':' -f2)
if [[ ! -z $value ]];
then
key="\"$key\""
value="\"$value\""
echo $key : $value
jq '.parameters |= map( if .name == '$key' then .default = '$value' else . end )' cam.json > cam1.json
mv cam1.json cam.json
fi
done < prop.properties
```

**property file**

```
git_con_type:something
git_host_fqdn:something again
git_user:something again again
git_user_password:something
git_repo:something
git_repo_user:
git_branch:
```

**JSON file**

```
{
"name": "${p:Instance_Name}",
  "parameters": [
    {
      "name": "git_con_type",
      "default": "",
      "immutable_after_create": false
    },
    {
      "name": "git_host_fqdn",
      "default": "hello",
      "immutable_after_create": false
    },
    {
      "name": "git_user",
      "default": "",
      "immutable_after_create": false
    },
    {
      "name": "git_user_password",
      "default": "Passw0rd",
      "immutable_after_create": false
    },
    {
      "name": "git_repo",
      "default": "lm",
      "immutable_after_create": false
    },
    {
      "name": "git_repo_user",
      "default": "-Life",
      "immutable_after_create": false
    },
    {
      "name": "git_branch",
      "default": "master",
      "immutable_after_create": false
    },
    {
      "name": "git_clone_dir",
      "default": "/opt/git",
      "immutable_after_create": false
    }
  ]
}
```

**Error**

> jq: error: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting QQSTRING_TEXT or QQSTRING_INTERP_START or QQSTRING_END (Unix shell quoting issues?) at , line 1:
>   .parameters |= map( if .name == "git_host_fqdn" then .default = "something
>   jq: error: Possibly unterminated 'if' statement at , line 1:
>   .parameters |= map( if .name == "git_host_fqdn" then .default = "something
>   jq: 2 compile errors

how can I make jq accept values with space? I have tried on jqplay with spaces and it works there, but not on the script.

Comment: Is it a quoting issue? try changing the quotes around `'.parameters ...` from single quotes to double quotes?

Comment: yes.. that fixed the issue.. i also had to remove the single quotes around the `$key` and `$value`. thanks

Comment: @solarc, that's a very dangerous "fix", especially as future versions of jq are going to have arbitrary file I/O support, meaning that injection attacks can not just change output but actually modify other content on your filesystem. It's much, **much** safer to pass data out-of-band from code instead, as the answer by peak shows.

Answer (score 3):

It would be much better to pass $key and $value into jq as illustrated in the following (deliberately minimalist) tweak of your script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line
do
  key=$(echo "$line" |cut -d':' -f1)
  value=$(echo "$line" |cut -d':' -f2)
  if [[ ! -z "$value" ]]
  then
     jq --arg key "$key" --arg value "$value" '.parameters |= map( if .name == $key then .default = $value else . end )' cam.json > cam1.json
     mv cam1.json cam.json
fi
done < prop.properties
```

It would be still better to avoid the bash loop altogether and do everything with just one invocation of jq.

### One-pass solution

The idea is to create a dictionary ($dict) of key-value pairs, which can easily be done using the builtin filter `INDEX/1`:

```
INDEX(inputs | split(":") | select(.[1] | length > 0); .[0])
| map_values(.[1]) as $dict
| $cam
| .parameters |= map( $dict[.name] as $value | if $value then .default = $value else . end )
```

### Invocation

With the above jq program in `program.jq`:

```
jq -n -R -f program.jq --argfile cam cam.json prop.properties > cam1.json && mv cam1.json cam.json
```

Or using `sponge`:

```
jq -n -R -f program.jq --argfile cam cam.json prop.properties | sponge cam.json
```

Note in particular the `-n` option, which is needed because program.jq uses `inputs`.

Comment: `while read line; do key=$(...); value=$(...)` should probably be changed to `while IFS=: read -r key value _`; do; no more need for the `cut`s that way.